# VBA to search last outlook mail conversation based on subject line which is a excel sheet column value

Tags: excel, vba, email, search, outlook

in my project i have excel sheet name " data"  which consist of a ID in column A

i want to search each ID in column A in outlook based on anywhere in the subject line. once i found i need to open the last conversation of that mail. after sending the reply mail i need to return value like "yes" in the same sheet against the ID

like wise the process should repeat for all the ID in the column.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1yrW.jpg)

[image]